# Does it make sense to build a text-based game Facebook app without using Facebook?

Tags: browser-based-games, facebook, text-based

If I am building a text-based browser game, does it make sense to build it on you domain first, without using the Facebook API?  I don't want to buy an SSL if I don't end up following through with everything. I already have a domain for testing.

In other words, can/should I build the whole thing outside of Facebook and then change it later to use the Facebook API?

Comment: There are cheap and even free means to get a decent useful certificate, like StartSSL.

Comment: @OskarDuveborn Thanks!  Do you think that free one from startssl will work?

Comment: Yes, it depends on the end-user device and not Facebook whether a certificate is trusted or not. There should be a list of which devices and operating systems are supported by default. I use StartSSL myself for a lab setup and have no problems even with most phones.

Comment: "Make sense" isn't really answerable, since that is just opinion. What makes sense for one person/situation is different from another. What you're actually asking is something like "is this possible, how much work would it be, and what are the constraints/considerations?" I would reword the title as "Is it possible to build a Facebook app on a separate domain first?"

Comment: @jhocking I like your middle version best.  "Is it possible" questions are also wishy-washy, because their binary answer depends on an opiniony summary of the constraints and considerations.  And to the OP: yes, you can.  Whether or not you should is much harder to answer.

Answer (score 1):

The majority of your code is not going to involve the Facebook API. It will be more work to integrate after code completion, but it's certainly possible to integrate it after the game has been written. Make sure you learn about any restrictions about Facebook apps that may impact the functionality of your game. So you can code around those.

Ultimately this is your decision. You need to weigh the possibility of completion against the cost of an SSL certificate. You should also consider the income that can potentially be generated from such a game, to see if you'd ever make your money back. Perhaps seek outside funding to get the SSL certificate.